# How to query JSON data from REST API in React Native

Tags: json, http, reactjs, react-native

I want to query through some data from NewsAPI in React Native and have no idea how to do so and none of the tutorials I've seen have helped. Thanks!

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you'll have more luck getting answers to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) on Networking from React Native... I'm using Fetch in our production apps.

> React Native provides the Fetch API for your networking needs. Fetch will seem familiar if you have used XMLHttpRequest or other networking APIs before. You may refer to MDN's guide on Using Fetch for additional information.

[MDN Fetch API Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
fetch('http://google.com')
 .then(res => {
    if (res.ok) return res.json())
    else throw new Error(res)
 .then(json => {
   for (var key in json) {
     // now you can parse it by calling json[key]
   }
 .catch(error => console.log(error)
 }
```

Comment: Their docs are kinda throwing me off... all I wanna do is get the JSON, parse through data and print it, I can't seem to find that only a network request. thanks for the help though!

Comment: I added an example... I agree the docs are confusing. You can probably get better examples on the web or in other people's code.

Comment: Ok thank you Brad! Is there a way I could print this now or call it in a <Text>?

Comment: You probably going to want to throw the json object into your component's state and then display that inside a `<Text/>` component.