# JSON Response Parsing Error - Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, json

I have the following JSON response coming from an API.

```
{
    "status": true,
    "cakes": {
        "7689": {
            "id": 7689,
            "flavor": "chocolate",
            "cookDetails": {
                "id": 101,
                "firstName": "Name1",
                "lastName": "LastName1"
            }
        },
        "7690": {
            "id": 7690,
            "flavor": "vanilla",
            "cookDetails": {
                "id": 102,
                "firstName": "Name2",
                "lastName": "LastName2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Language I'm using to parse this JSON: Javascript

Framework: ReactNative

My question is:

**1. Is the JSON format correct?**

**2. If yes, then how do I parse it (NOTE: I don't know the value of id in cakes until I parse it)?**

PS: New to the framework. Big thanks.

Comment: Your JSON isn't correct , check here https://jsonlint.com/, you have 3 useless comma. 2 at the end of `LastName` and at the very end

Comment: JSON is incorrect. Colon is not allowed before {

Comment: JOSN is incorrect

Comment: 3x trailing `,` is the problem

Comment: @Miller - erm, yes, they are

Comment: I have corrected the JSON response. Can someone answer the second question (How to parse it)? @AshBringer

Comment: I guess JSON.parse can manage it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384690/how-to-query-json-data-from-rest-api-in-react-native

Comment: Are you able to change the format of the data from the API? It would be easier for you if cakes were an array, excluding the outer id key. That way you can access the items by their index.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this,

```
{
    "status": true,
    "cakes": [{
        "id": 7689,
        "flavor": "chocolate",
        "cookDetails": {
            "id": 101,
            "firstName": "Name1",
            "lastName": "LastName1"
        }
    }, {
        "id": 7690,
        "flavor": "vanilla",
        "cookDetails": {
            "id": 102,
            "firstName": "Name2",
            "lastName": "LastName2"
        }
    }]
}
```

for ReactNative check this :https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html
http://www.9lessons.info/2017/04/react-native-json-parsing-and-helper.html

> Note below code HTML JavaScript for your understanding.

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"status": true,"cakes": [{"id": 7689,"flavor": "chocolate","cookDetails": {"id": 101,"firstName": "Name1","lastName": "LastName1"}},{"id": 7690,"flavor": "vanilla","cookDetails": {"id": 102,"firstName": "Name2","lastName": "LastName2"}}]}');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var obj = JSON.parse('{"status": true,"cakes": [{"id": 7689,"flavor": "chocolate","cookDetails": {"id": 101,"firstName": "Name1","lastName": "LastName1"}},{"id": 7690,"flavor": "vanilla","cookDetails": {"id": 102,"firstName": "Name2","lastName": "LastName2"}}]}');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.cakes[0].id +", "+ obj.cakes[0].flavor+", "+obj.cakes[0].cookDetails.id+", "+obj.cakes[0].cookDetails.firstName+", "+obj.cakes[0].cookDetails.lastName;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is valid JSON(just extra commas were removed):

```
{
    "status": true,
    "cakes": {
        "7689": {
            "id": 7689,
            "flavor": "chocolate",
            "cookDetails": {
                "id": 101,
                "firstName": "Name1",
                "lastName": "LastName1"
            }
        },
        "7690": {
            "id": 7690,
            "flavor": "vanilla",
            "cookDetails": {
                "id": 102,
                "firstName": "Name2",
                "lastName": "LastName2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can parse it with plain JSON.parse call

Comment: This is not the complete answer I guess. Please be aware of complete answer before answering the question. If you have a hint just go with comments.

Comment: @slesh I have updated the JSON response. Can you answer the second question (How to parse it)?